# Delete a row with particular value in column

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I want to delete all rows in which particular columns have value 1

For example consider the following list:

```
x=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]
```

I want to delete the rows that have one on first and third column. So my expected output is,

```
x=[[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1]]
```

Comment: `x[~x[:, [0, 2]].any(1)]`  If you  have a `numpy` array

Comment: @user3483203 thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The list:

```
In [33]: x=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1
    ...: ],[0,0,1,0]]
```

array equivalent:

```
In [34]: arr = np.array(x)                                                      
In [35]: arr                                                                    
Out[35]: 
array([[1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0],
       [1, 0, 0, 0],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 0, 1, 0]])
```

testing columns:

```
In [36]: arr[:,[0,2]]                                                           
Out[36]: 
array([[1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1],
       [1, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 0],
       [0, 1]])
```

mask identifying rows that have a 1 in either of those columns:

```
In [37]: arr[:,[0,2]].any(axis=1)                                               
Out[37]: array([ True, False, False,  True,  True, False, False,  True])
```

apply that mask to delete rows; equivalently, to retain the other rows:

```
In [38]: arr[~_, :]                                                             
Out[38]: 
array([[0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1],
       [0, 1, 0, 0],
       [0, 0, 0, 1]])
```

`arr` is not changed; this is a new array.

The general idea is to construct a mask, or boolean array, that identifies the elements you want to keep, and use that to create a new array.

Using a list comprehension on the original list:

```
In [45]: [row for row in x if not any(row[j] for j in [0,2])]                   
Out[45]: [[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
x=[[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0],[1,0,0,0],[0,1,0,0],[0,0,0,1],[0,0,1,0]]

y = [l for l in x if l[0] != 1 and l[2] != 1]
print(y)
```

Output

```
[[0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1], [0, 1, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0, 1]]
```

Comment: If i have 100s of columns, I cannot write this manually. Can you give a general solution?